# How do I stay evolved?

Tags: pokemon-super-mystery-dungeon

I have looked on 4 websites and 2 said you could not evolve and 2 said you could, but not how. Can I stay evolved and if so, how?

Comment: If my answer has helped you, be sure to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are able to have your starter Pokémon evolve, but only after you've completed the main story. There are temporary evolutions throughout the story, but you can only evolve permanently after the main story. From this [Serebii page on Evolution in Pokémon Super Mystery Dungeon](http://serebii.net/supermysterydungeon/evolution.shtml):

> While temporary evolution of the player and partner characters does occur throughout the story, being able to evolve Pokémon you recruit is not available until you have finished the main part of the story. **Furthermore, you will not be able to evolve your starter or partner characters until you have completed the epilogue.**

This page also explains the process of evolving your Pokémon:

> To evolve, you simply have to take a ride on Lapras over to the Life Tree and speak to Xerneas. Xerneas will offer to let your Pokémon evolve, though it will ask you twice to make sure you want the evolution. Once it's agreed, the Pokémon goes into the forest and comes back evolved.